# Activity preview for Transparent Activity (KitKat)

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

On Android 4.4 Kitkat, My main Activity has a transparent statusbar & navigation bar, and I use [SystemBarTint](https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint) for coloring them.

```
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
    <item name="android:clipToPadding">true</item>
```

The problem is how does it looks on the Activity preivew.
As you can see, the status bar and the navigation bar got the white color, because the background is white.
When the activity finally loads, SystemBarTint change their color to dark purple.
Their white color on loading make the loading looks ugly.

Is there a way to set the status bar and the navigation bar color (pre Android L) so it will show their color on the Activity preview?

[image]